# React component to render localized text (props)

Tags: reactjs, localization

I'm trying to render a localized text comming from a REST API. Let's say the props looks like (the format can be changed anyway):

```
"name": {
    "default": "Clock",
    "en": "Clock",
    "de": "Uhr"
}
```

And the output should be a text for the current locale. Is there a component capable of that?

All I found when searching for "i18n in React" are  libraries/modules/components that render localized text from static localized files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you are currently handling defining the current locale. You can create your own component, for example `RenderTextLocale` which you can connect to Redux or similar state management tool, where you have current locale saved. Then when calling this component, pass the whole text object to it: `<RenderTextLocale text={name} />` and inside the component resolve the currently selected locale to the attribute of the object, i.e. if current locale is `en` then render `name['en']`.

Comment: I thought there is a ready to use component for that. But you are right. It is easy to implement. Thanks.